# How to run some codes by confirming the confirm() box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `confirm()` box. When The `confirm()` method displays a dialog box with a specified message, along with an OK and a Cancel button, I want with OK a function will be run`(myfunction())`. In `myfunction()` I want to run some codes of my page. How Can I run a piece of my code that are in page by pressing OK on `confirm()` box:

```
if (confirm('continue?')) {
    myfunction()
}
function myfunction(){
//Here I want to run this request below
}
```

**Edited:**
Actually I want the below code would not be run until pressing OK of confirm() box.

```
<div class="test">Test</div>
<basis core="cookie" name="supplier" value="test" />
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: That's how you'd do it...I think. Your question isn't really clear right now.

Comment: In the executable code snippet your code seems working as you expect!!!

Comment: @Jack Bashford please look at `Edited` part.Sorry for bad explanation.Is it more understandable now?

Comment: This is still extremely unclear.. do you want to append the tags to something?

Comment: No, For example I want to show `div` by `class` test or set the `test` in cookie.Some codes must be run  if user accept it not running by default.

Comment: So put `document.querySelector"(.test").style.display = "block";` in `myfunction()`. That has nothing to do with the confirmation box.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this part of the code you got right:

```
if (confirm('continue?')) {
    myfunction()
}
function myfunction(){
    // function body
}
```

And then you mentioned you wanted to set something inside `myfunction`, although this is totally unrelated, and I'm still not sure what you meant. It might look something like this:

```
function myfunction(){
    document.querySelector(".test").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("basis").setAttribute("value", "test");
}
```